# how to make AHK script for use with outlook quick steps

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make an ahk script which would help me more easily activate the Outlook 2013 quickstep shortcut Clt+Shf+1 which I wish to use as a way to quickly put processed emails into a specific folder.

I find the default Clt+Shf+1 quickstep shortcut in Outlook that is applied to this quick step not very easy to press consistently and so wish to make an ahk script that will instead make the shortcut Alt+1 activate Clt+Shf+1 within Outlook.

I am new to ahk and, whilst I have had some success, I am doing something wrong here.

I tried the following but they don't work:

!1:: Send {^+1}  ; Alt+1 gives Clt+Shft+1

and

!1::^+1  ;  Alt+1 gives Clt+Shft+1

Thanks for any advice on what I should do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!1:: Send {^+1}` is wrong because you're not supposed to use `{ }`, and `!1::^+1` is almost right, but it's just going to keep the Alt key pressed in there as well due to some more in-depth reasons.

The correct way would be:
`!1::SendInput, ^+1`
([SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is the recommended send mode, but just normal `Send` would work as well)

---

Also, you might want to use a context sensitive hotkey for this so the hotkey only works when the Outlook app is open.
For this you'd use `#IfWinActive`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)</sup> like this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe outlook.exe
!1::SendInput, ^+1
#IfWinActive
```

(I don't actually know for sure that the Outlook window comes from an executable named `outlook.exe`, I'm just assuming. You might need to change it to the correct exe)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer - this really helped me!

Comment: If an answer solved your problem @user90175, please accept it so that other people know that the question is resolved